# .htacces redirect from upper case to lower case, except the last part of the URL

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I need to redirect all address in my website from upper case to lower case, except the last part of the URL.

For example, I want to change

`www.domain.com/a/B/C/XpTo`

To

`www.domain.com/a/b/c/XpTo`

Only the last part (XpTo) remained unchanged.

However, I can also have:

`www.domain.com/A/XpTo`

And I need:

`www.domain.com/a/XpTo`

That is, even with a small path, only the last part must remain unchanged. How can I achieve that with .htaccess, without using RewriteMap in the Apache config file?

This is what I have tried:

```bash
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond expr "tolower(%{REQUEST_URI}) =~ /(.*)/"
RewriteRule [A-Z] %1 [R=302,L]
```

Comment: I have tested with the following code, but that changes all parts to lower case, and I need the last part (whereaver the number of url parts) to be unchanged.

RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond expr "tolower(%{REQUEST_URI}) =~ /(.*)/"

RewriteRule [A-Z] %1 [R=302,L]

Comment: By the way, the url will always consist of, at least, two parts after the domain. For example: www.domain.com/a/XpTo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your shown code will convert all of `REQUEST_URI` to lower case.

You can use a regex in `RewriteRule` pattern to match last part component separately from rest of URI and capture in a group. That can be used to put original value back on `RewriteRule` target.

Similarly leave last part component out of capture group in `RewriteCond` as well to get URI part before last component captured in `%1`.

You may use this code:

```bash
RewriteCond expr "tolower(%{REQUEST_URI}) =~ m#(.+/)[^/]+/?$#"
RewriteRule ^[^A-Z]*[A-Z].*/([^/]+/?)$ %1$1 [R=302,L,NE]
```